# Diferença entre datas localizadas em linhas e colunas diferentes

Tags: r, dplyr

No R, eu tenho os seguintes dados:

```
entrada      saida        id   ordem
2013-01-15   2013-05-20   1    1     
2015-03-13   2015-09-12   1    2      
2016-01-12   2016-04-11   1    3
```

Quero acrescentar uma coluna com a diferença (dias) entre a saida (1) e a entrada (2) e assim por diante, considerando o id e a ordem dos registros. Segue um exemplo:

```
entrada      saida        id   ordem  diferenca
2013-01-15   2013-05-20   1    1      
2015-03-13   2015-09-12   1    2      662
2016-01-12   2016-04-11   1    3      122
2013-01-01   2013-01-30   2    1      
2014-06-18   2015-09-02   2    2      504
2016-02-26   2017-02-11   2    3      177
2018-03-04   2018-12-16   2    4      386
```

Comment: Não é uma duplicata. Quero calcular a diferença de datas localizadas em colunas e linhas diferentes.

Comment: Então a pergunta tem que ser mais clara. Como é que tem uma diferença de zero dias? Quais são as datas que entram no cálculo de cada valor da coluna `diferenca`?

Comment: Rui, obrigada pela dica. Eu editei o exemplo, e retirei o zero. A diferença é entre a data da  saída (ex. 2013-05-20) e a entrada seguinte (ex. 2015-03-13), e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefiro [a solução do Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412407/117168) porque só precisa do pacote base e segue o princípio funcional do R, mas eis uma resposta com `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
# Converte para data.table. Ou carregue seus dados usando `fread`

df1 <- df1[order(id, ordem)]
# Garante que seus dados estejam ordenados

df1[, `:=`(entrada = as.IDate(entrada), saida = as.IDate(saida))]
# Converte para datas (usando o formato providenciado pelo data.table)

df1[, diferenca := entrada - shift(saida, 1), by = id]

> df1
      entrada      saida id ordem diferenca
1: 2013-01-15 2013-05-20  1     1        NA
2: 2015-03-13 2015-09-12  1     2       662
3: 2016-01-12 2016-04-11  1     3       122
4: 2013-01-01 2013-01-30  2     1        NA
5: 2014-06-18 2015-09-02  2     2       504
6: 2016-02-26 2017-02-11  2     3       177
7: 2018-03-04 2018-12-16  2     4       386
```

Você pode substituir os NAs por 0, mas é uma boa prática manter a distinção (neste caso, 0 corresponde a quando a data de saída de uma linha é a mesma da entrada da linha seguinte, enquanto NA corresponde à primeira linha de cada id).

Comment: Obrigada, @CarlosEduardoLagosta!

Answer (score 2):

A seguinte função faz o cálculo que a pergunta pede, com as diferenças calculadas para cada `id`.

Note que as colunas de datas têm de ser de classe `"Date"`.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  f <- function(X){
    c(0, X[[1]][-1] - X[[2]][-nrow(X)])
  }
  unname(unlist(by(DF, DF[['id']], f)))
}

fun(df1)
#[1]   0 662 122   0 504 177 386

all.equal(df1$diferenca, fun(df1))
#[1] TRUE
```

**Dados.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
entrada      saida        id   ordem  diferenca
2013-01-15   2013-05-20   1    1      0
2015-03-13   2015-09-12   1    2      662
2016-01-12   2016-04-11   1    3      122
2013-01-01   2013-01-30   2    1      0
2014-06-18   2015-09-02   2    2      504
2016-02-26   2017-02-11   2    3      177
2018-03-04   2018-12-16   2    4      386
", header = TRUE)

df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], as.Date)
```

Comment: me perdoe a ignorância, mas onde coloco as datas?

Comment: @MarliRocha As datas? Quer dizer o valor de `fun(df1)`? Se sim, pode fazer `df1$diferenca <- fun(df1)`.

Comment: Não. Estou com dificuldade de usar essa função. O que coloco no DF, X, as datas de entrada e saída.. @RuiBarradas

Comment: @MarliRocha No `DF` e no `X` **não coloca nada**. Basta chamar a função tal e qual está no exemplo. Desde que as datas sejam a 1ª e 2ª colunas, `fun(df1)` calcula tudo sózinha.